# Generate a list

Tags: javascript, html

So I want to generate a list from an Array I wrote the following code:

```
function list() {

    table = new Array("Rabat", "Casablanca", "Marrakech", "Fes", "Tanger", "Agadir");
    document.write('<select id="list1" size=6><option value="Rabat">Rabat</option><option     value="Casablanca">Casablanca</option></select>');

}
```

It works but I'm wondering if there's a better coding

Comment: Better how? Might be a better fit for http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Certainly. A couple of issues: Don't create implicit globals, always use `var` when you declare a variable. Don't use `document.write` after the document was completely loaded. It will replace the whole document. Use DOM manipulation instead. Also, you don't even seem to be using your array.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about codereview.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a loop to go through all items in the list:

```
// you can use this instead of the new Array() syntax:
var table = ["Rabat", "Casablanca", "Marrakech", "Fes", "Tanger", "Agadir"];
var select = '<select id="list1" size="6">';
for (var i=0; i<table.length; i++) {
    select += '<option value="' + table[i] + '">' + table[i] + '</option>';
}
select += '</select>';
document.write(select); //you should probably not use document.write though...
```

Usually it is better not to use `document.write` though. Instead, you should try selecting the element you want to append to, and then add the text to that.

Comment: stop feeding kids that don't know google

Comment: @leblma does that make this answer bad?

Comment: @leblma Down-voting a valid answer doesn't make sense. Flag/down-vote the question.

Comment: You might consider `array.join()` rather than string concatonation.

Comment: @Andy you should probably post that as a seperate answer, since it's your idea to do it that way.

Comment: I downvoted the question. I'm only making a comment on your answer because you might find it useful/good practice.

Comment: @Andy Just because you got me wondering, I made http://jsperf.com/join-or-loop, so as you can see, the performance speed is indeed in `join`'s favour, but it's not really a big difference. I think the loops are just a bit clearer to read.

Comment: Me too @Joeytje50. I think that's the first time someone's gone off to do some research based on something I wrote here. Kudos. [You might find some of the information here interesting](http://code.google.com/p/jslibs/wiki/JavascriptTips#Multiple_string_concatenation).

Answer (score 1):

HTML:

```
<select id="list1" size="6"></select>
```

JS:

```
function list() {
    var i,
        table = ["Rabat", "Casablanca", "Marrakech", "Fes", "Tanger", "Agadir"],
        select = document.getElementById('list1'),
        out;

    for (i = 0; i < table.length; ++i) {
        out += "<option value='" + table[i] + "'>" + table[i] + "</option>";
    }

    select.innerHTML = out;
}
```

FIDDLE:
http://jsfiddle.net/Z9XKp/

Comment: You should probably also use quotes around the `size` attribute's value.

Answer (score 0):

you can loop over the array and make your string rather than writing same code again and again .

```
var list="";
for(i=0;i<table.length;i++){
var val=table[i];
  list+="<option value='"+val+"'>"+val+"</option";
 }
```